# radio button submission in javascript returns the first value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

hello every body i have a code that submits a few text inputs along with a radio box together the problem is that all text inputs are submitted correct but the radio button sends the first value 
here is my html code:

```
<form  action="process.php" method="POST">

    <!-- NAME -->
    <div id="name-group" class="form-group">
        <label for="name">لینک بنر</label>
        <input type="url" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="http://example.com">
        <!-- errors will go here -->
    </div>

    <!-- EMAIL -->
    <div id="email-group" class="form-group">
        <label for="email">تعداد کل کلیک</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="15000">
        <!-- errors will go here -->
    </div>

    <!-- SUPERHERO ALIAS -->
    <div id="superhero-group" class="form-group">
        <label for="superheroAlias">تعداد کلیک روزانه</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="superheroAlias" placeholder="حداقل 1000">
        <!-- errors will go here -->
    </div>


        <input type="radio"  name="position" value="head" > 
            <img alt="" src="../membership/images/head.jpg" style="width: 10%; height:auto;" align="absmiddle">

        <input type="radio" name="position" value="right" > 
            <img alt="" src="../membership/images/col-right.jpg" style="width: 10%; height:auto;" align="absmiddle">

        <input type="radio" name="position" value="left"  >
            <img alt="" src="../membership/images/col-left.jpg" style="width: 10%; height:auto;" align="absmiddle">


    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit <span class="fa fa-arrow-right"></span></button>

</form>
```

and my js file that processes this code is :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

// process the form
$('form').submit(function(event) {

    $('.form-group').removeClass('has-error'); // remove the error class
    $('.help-block').remove(); // remove the error text

    // get the form data
    // there are many ways to get this data using jQuery (you can use the class or id also)
    var formData = {
        'name'              : $('input[name=name]').val(),
        'email'             : $('input[name=email]').val(),
        'superheroAlias'    : $('input[name=superheroAlias]').val(),
        'position'          : $('input[name=position]:checked').val()
    };

    // process the form
    $.ajax({
        type        : 'POST', // define the type of HTTP verb we want to use (POST for our form)
        url         : 'process.php', // the url where we want to POST
        data        : formData, // our data object
        dataType    : 'json', // what type of data do we expect back from the server
        encode      : true
    })
```

Comment: how is this a php related question?

Comment: if you want multiple options, use checkboxes, why radios?

Comment: no i want one variable from radio button and the others from text boxes but the problem is the result for radio buttons just submits head even when other options are selected

Comment: `$('input[name=position]:checked').value` should return selected value.

Comment: @Prajwal       i tried but the same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) try to add event.preventDefault(); inside form submit event on top

2) set var formData = $('form').serialize();

this code works perfectly :

```
    <form  action="" method="POST">
    <div id="name-group" class="form-group">
        <label for="name">لینک بنر</label>
        <input type="url" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="http://example.com">
    </div>
    <div id="email-group" class="form-group">
        <label for="email">تعداد کل کلیک</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="15000">
    </div>
    <div id="superhero-group" class="form-group">
        <label for="superheroAlias">تعداد کلیک روزانه</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="superheroAlias" placeholder="حداقل 1000">
    </div>
        <input type="radio"  name="position" value="head" />
        <input type="radio" name="position" value="right" />
        <input type="radio" name="position" value="left"  />
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit <span class="fa fa-arrow-right"></span></button>
</form>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('form').submit(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
var formData = $('form').serialize();
console.log(formData);});
});
</script>
```

Comment: i have it just did not included the full code here.

Comment: i did it but the result is same it only submits the first option however i checked lets say second option

Comment: i have checked and added the code that works perfectly see the code